# Questions regarding internal code of a try catch block previous to an exception

Tags: java, android, try-catch

I have a try catch block like this:

```
     try {
            try {
                GeoPoint dummy = new  GeoPoint(0, 0);
                deviceCompatibleWithMaps=true;
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                deviceCompatibleWithMaps=false;
            }

            functionThatCanCrash();
     } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
     }
```

`GeoPoint dummy = new  GeoPoint(0, 0)` will never fail in my nexus 5x testing device. `deviceCompatibleWithMaps` is a global variable.

The global variable deviceCompatibleWithMaps should store the true value in all cases when the device is not giving an exception in the inner try-catch block? or it is possible that if the Throwable is Error or Exception is thrown in the upper trycatch block is thrown its value does not get saved?

I have a rare error in one app, in which sometimes the value of the global is not being stored, and I'm suspecting that asignations executed below an exception on a try catch block will not be safely stored.

Comment: Why not put `this.globalBool = true;` outside try? or in `finally` block?

Comment: it is just a sample code, the real code is much more complex

Comment: you should provide your specific issue. This code `globalBool` will alway be true.

Comment: `globalBool` is not a global variable.

Comment: "It's just a sample code" - yes, but a sample of what? Not of the problem you're asking about.  Therefore it's useless.

Comment: edited adding some more sample code, and yes, I know that I can put the asignment below the try block but I want to understand why is happening this

Comment: @LewBloch I edited the post

Comment: @EduardoDennis you can take a look now too

Comment: It's an antipattern to `catch (Throwable)`. The only line in your inner `try` that could throw an exception is the `new GeoPoint` allocation. Is that constructor declared to throw an exception? You don't show it, so we don't know. If not, then get rid of the inner `try` section. If so, then catch the specific exception. Same with `functionThatCanCrash`. It's impossible to answer your question intelligently with insufficient information.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how `this.globalBool = true;` could ever fail, so it would always be set to true, unless the code in `functionWhichCrash()` changes it (other another thread).

EDIT: The question has completely changed since I wrote this answer.  New answer:

If `GeoPoint dummy = new  GeoPoint(0, 0);` fails, `deviceCompatibleWithMaps` will never be set to true.

Comment: yes I know, the problem is that such function is never failing in a nexus 5X, the problem is not there

Comment: When you say *the value of the global is not being stored*, do you mean *the value of the global is not being set to true*?  As it is, if that line never fails, only another thread or code inside `functionThatCanCrash();` could set it to false.

Answer (score 1):

If the initialization of `GeoPoint` throws an exception the boolean is never set to true. If you use `Boolean` as an object it will be `null`, but if you use primitive `boolean` it will default to false. You should try to change to

```
try {
    GeoPoint dummy = new  GeoPoint(0, 0);
    deviceCompatibleWithMaps = true;
    functionThatCanCrash();

    } catch (CustomException t) {
       // logic for one exception
    } catch (CalendarNotCompatibleException t) {
       // logic for other exception
       deviceCompatibleWithMaps = false;
    }
}
```

### You should never catch Throwable.

Notice in the Exception hierarchy `Throwable` is at the top. Every `Error`, `Exception`, `RuntimeException`, etc. extends from `Throwable`. You will be catching every possible error that happens in your application.

[image]

The JavaDoc from the Error class specifically says these exceptions should not be caught.

```
* An <code>Error</code> is a subclass of <code>Throwable</code> 
 * that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application 
 * should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions. 
 * The <code>ThreadDeath</code> error, though a "normal" condition,
 * is also a subclass of <code>Error</code> because most applications
 * should not try to catch it. 

 * A method is not required to declare in its <code>throws</code> 
 * clause any subclasses of <code>Error</code> that might be thrown 
 * during the execution of the method but not caught, since these 
 * errors are abnormal conditions that should never occur. 
 *
 * @author  Frank Yellin
 * @version %I%, %G%
 * @see     java.lang.ThreadDeath
 * @since   JDK1.0
```